# How to process some operation in some directory?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Here is my try :

```
#!/Usr/bin/emacs --script
(let ((default-directory "/home/vision"))
  (shell-command "git pull;")
```

but it doesn't work properly, I need to git pull in /home/vision directory and make some more actions there. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directory paths should end with a trailing slash.

The docstring in <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `default-directory` <kbd>RET</kbd> is explicit about that, in fact.

Fixing that ought to fix your problem.

See also:

- `cd` function.
- `file-name-as-directory` function.